# VBA Error 424 with Empty

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have tried looking for questions with the error 424, but I didn't find any that matched my situation.

I am getting a 424 error on the 3rd line :

```
For icount = 2 To no_items
    If hid.Cells(icount, 1).Value > 0 Then
        'If hid.Cells(icount, 1).Offset(-1).Value Is Empty Then
            'hid.Cells(icount, 1).Value = 1
        'Else
            hid.Cells(icount, 1).Value = 1 + hid.Cells(icount, 1).Value
        'End If
    End If
Next
```

My declaration is as follow :

```
Dim hid As Worksheet
Set hid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hidden")
hid.Visible = True
```

Before, I had the same error on line 2 with :

```
If hid.Cells(icount, 1) is not empty Then
```

I don't understand why there is an error, everything is defined the way it should. 
Can you help me please?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax used for **Not ISEmpty** is not correct, you need to change your line of :

```
If hid.Cells(icount, 1) is not empty Then
```

To:

```
If Not IsEmpty(hid.Cells(icount, 1)) Then
```

Comment: I changed the empty with the value 0, and it works. Is the 'is empty' function just for strings?*

Comment: @AmandineFAURILLOU your code syntax and where you place your `Not IsEmpty` is wrong. you can also modify to `If hid.Cells(icount, 1).Offset(-1).Value <> "" Then`